# how to solve wordpress localhost database error

Tags: database, wordpress, localhost

Hello I am trying to make a localhost wordpress website before taking it to host. but during the process of wordpress installation I face the problem as below

To allow use of this page to automatically repair database problems, please add the following line to your wp-config.php file. Once this line is added to your config, reload this page.

define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);

How could I solve this issue for localhost because on youtube they show some cpanel for the website

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `wp-config.php` file (it will be in the web root of your local web server - if you're on Windows this may be XAMPP.)

Add `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` to the end of `wp-config.php`

I found a guide to running WordPress on your local machine (Windows): https://themeisle.com/blog/install-xampp-and-wordpress-locally/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have not followed the proper steps to install WordPress on the localhost.

Yes, you can go to the root of your local webserver and you can find the wp-config.php file. Here you can add define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true); Then open the website again.

As it is a fresh WordPress installation there should not be any issues. So I would recommend you to start it from scratch.

1. Install XAMPP server to run Apache and MySQL
2. Create a DB
3. Download WordPress and configure the DB
4. Install WordPress.

Here is a good step by step procedure on how to install WordPress on localhost with images.
https://studentprojects.in/articles/computer-science/how-to-setup-wordpress-on-windows-localhost-xampp/